# Integration Tests .NET 6 - 404 not Found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, integration-testing, integration

I was trying to write integeration tests using the same set of actions that I have earlier used in other microservices on my project.

Creating a Client using a specific set of environment variables

Adding authentication headers

This is where the test fails, after auth is set (checked this) , I am not able to reach the controller endpoint itself, I'm guessing the host is not building properly?? But if that is the case, then I should be getting something in response apart from 404. I just get redirected to dispose off resources and that's it. I haven't been able to figure this out, again, this has been used on multiple occasions in a number of tests which are fine.

Can someone point out where to exactly look for or have experienced something like this maybe????

```
    public async Task Users(string url)
    {
        //Act
        var http = factory.CreateClient();
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, $"/api/v1/Account/{url}");
      
        await request.AddWamHeaders();
        var response = await http.SendAsync(request);
        Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync());
        //Assert
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        JObject data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        Assert.True(data["Data"].Count() > 1);
        Assert.Equal("application/json; charset=utf-8",
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the code of how are you creating `factory` and also the relevant code actual service host being built? did you try debugging the test to see if there is any exception in the service while starting up?

Answer (score 1):

public class AccountControllerEndTest : IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory>
{
private readonly WebApplicationFactory factory;

```
    public AccountControllerEndTest(WebApplicationFactory<Program> factory)
    {
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("ASSET_GROUP", "test");
        this.factory = factory.WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
        {
            builder.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
            builder.UseEnvironment("test");
            builder.UseConfiguration(new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.test.json")
                .Build());
            Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
        });
    }
```

This is how I was building the Host, the class fixture decorates the host with the config you set as provided in my given config file, I had to change the directory first, because the test project does not locate the json from the root of the peer . The issue was that the Program.cs should be accepting a set of **args** while creating a builder , it was null for me originally, and the host was not building because the fixture class was not able to dictate the configurations to the host.